# Hadoop dfsadmin -shutdownDatanode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

What is meant by ipc_port? What should i pass as an argument in

```
-shutdownDatanode <datanode_host:ipc_port> [upgrade]]
-getDatanodeInfo <datanode_host:ipc_port>]
```

I entered  `hdfs dfsadmin -shutdownDatanode impc2390.htcitmr:22`

It throwed an error

> shutdownDatanode: Failed on local exception:
>   com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is:
>   "impc2361.htcitmr/192.168.10.104"; destination host is:
>   "impc2390.htcitmr":22;

```
my /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.101  impc2391.htcitmr impc2391
192.168.10.103  impc2390.htcitmr impc2390
192.168.10.102  impc2359.htcitmr impc2359
192.168.10.104  impc2361.htcitmr impc2361
192.168.10.105  impc2389.htcitmr impc2389
```

Please kindly help

Comment: I tried with the ip address of the computer as well but still throwing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using port 22? Can you check your configuration on DataNode to find the correct port? By [default](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) it is 50020:

**dfs.datanode.ipc.address:**   0.0.0.0:50020   The datanode ipc server address and port.

You can find this parameter in your local data node in **hdfs-site.xml** file located in hadoop catalog.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. Problem solved.But could you just tell me where to find the ipc address of datanode.